# How do I prevent the PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied, while trying to connect my pc and raspberry pi with socket?

Tags: python, sockets, raspberry-pi

my code is:

```
import socket
import os
s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 22
s.bind((host,port))
print("")
print("server currently running @ ", host)
print("")
print("Waiting for any incoming connections...")
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print("")
print(addr, "connected well")

while 1:
    command = input("Enter command: ")
    conn.send(command.encode())
    conn.recv(1024)
    print("command executed well")
```

The error given is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/server.py", line 6 in <module>
    s.bind((host,port))
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I am still quite new to using socket but I have made sure that my internet has no socket firewalls and the pc and raspberry pi should connect so could somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong or point me in the right direction? Please and thank you.

Comment: The low ports are usually reserved. `22` is typically used by ssh. Recommend trying a port in the 3000-50000 range.

Comment: Port 22 is within the range of privileged ports that require elevated permissions to use (ports < 1024). Just use a larger port that isn't already in use, like 5555.

Comment: Thanks it has gotten rid of the error, now I just need to figure out how to fix error 10060 haha, have a nice day.